# Starting new thread for every new class/activity java android

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading

I wrote program that work fine. Every class is one new activity, that show you some information from web... for example contacts-activity.class takes information from json-contacts and invoices-activity.class pull info from json-invoices out.
But I think my code doesn´t look like good, because in every class I start new Thread for network operations to pull my data from web-server.
How can I try to do it better?

Comment: you think your code doesn´t look like good then how can we say it's good or not if we didn't get a chance to see it. Be specific and put codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your business and threading logic into separate class and interact with it from your `Activities`.

Comment: I read somewhere that you cant start more then one thread in the same scope

Comment: @sausagerus what is "same scope"? Can you link? You can start as many threads as you wish.

Comment: AFAIK, the number of threads is related to the processor. You can't simply start 10 threads, I think.

Comment: @Fustigador nope ) You can **start** as many threads as you wish. There is no limitation. But CPU will execute only one thread per core every moment. So e.g. you can start 10 threads, but only 2 will be simultaneously in execution phase every moment if CPU has only 2 core.

Comment: @Alexey, with same scope i mean place between  {  ...  }

Comment: @sausagerus, you can start threads even within scope of cycle `for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {new Thread().start(); new Thread().start();}` and it works.

Comment: @Alexey, I´am just tried to do something like that ' for(int i = 0; i <=1; i++){ if(0 == i) { ThreadA.start(); }else { ThreadB.start();} ' ... didnt work for me , but if i start threadA or ThreadB separate than its work. why?)